# Process buffer in chunk sizes

Tags: c#

I have an `IRandomAccessStream` to store data on WindowsPhone 8.1 and I want to process the data in a certain BLOCKSIZE.

Here is the code

in the capture function:

```
await this.mediaCapture.StartRecordToStreamAsync(recordProfile, this.message);
```

in the stop function, when done I stop:

```
await this.mediaCapture.StopRecordAsync();

using (var dataReader = new DataReader(message.GetInputStreamAt(0)))
{
    dataReader.UnicodeEncoding = Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8;
    dataReader.ByteOrder = Windows.Storage.Streams.ByteOrder.LittleEndian;

    //  await dataReader.LoadAsync((uint)message.Size);
    await dataReader.LoadAsync(((uint)message.Size + (int)FREQUENCY) * 10);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[((int)message.Size + (int)FREQUENCY) * 10];

    dataReader.ReadBytes(buffer);

    short[] signal = new short[BLOCKSIZE];
    int bufferReadResult = 0;

    while (bufferReadResult != buffer.Length) 
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < BLOCKSIZE; index += 2, bufferReadResult++)
        {
            signal[bufferReadResult] = BitConverter.ToInt16(buffer, index);

        }

        // .....process the signal[] in BLOCKSIZE,
        // keep processing BLOCKSIZE until end of buffer
        // so process [BLOCKSIZE][BLOCKSIZE]..............buffer end
    }
}
```

The problem is that when `bufferReadResult` reaches BLOCKSIZE that's it. It won't continue with a new block unit end of buffer.

What is the best way to do this? I have a buffer or `IRandomAccessStream` and I want to process the all the data in chunks of `short[BLOCKSIZE]`.

Comment: From your code snippet, I don't see how bufferReadResult reaches BLOCKSIZE.. the for-loop will run only BLOCKSIZE/2 times.  ??

Comment: Without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly illustrates the problem, there's no way to answer this well. The code you posted doesn't make sense either; `dataReader.ReadBytes(buffer);` won't even compile, as the parameter is an `out` parameter, the processing loop runs the risk of overrunning the lengths of both `buffer` and `signal`, and the way the loop is written, you will just process the same `BLOCKSIZE` bytes from `buffer` over and over again. Please provide a better code example, and be more precise about what's wrong.

Comment: ok I use the dataReader to read the contents from a IRandomAccessStream and place into byte buffer. The real issue is from that buffer or any buffer is to read out bytes in chunks {BLOCKSIZE] convert to short[BLOCKSIZE], process these shorts[] in a separate function and continue doing that until the end of the buffer. Ensuring that the indexing is correct, and the destination array is the correct size.